# Unable to renew token with adal.js

Tags: adal, adal.js

I'm using Javascript (without Angular) to add AAD authentication to my single page web app. The initial login works fine, but after an hour, the token expires, and I am unable to renew it with acquireToken. I've tried calling acquireToken when I am still logged in with my clientID and it works fine, but after the token expires, I can't renew it. It fails with "Token renewal operation failed due to timeout".

After the token expires, I ran this:

```
// ADALContext created from calling new AuthenticationContext
// passed in same clientID to acquire token as to create ADALContext 
ADALContext.acquireToken(clientID, function (error, token) {console.log(error, token)})
```

I've enabled oauth2AllowImplicitFlow in AAD.

```
  "keyCredentials": [],
  "knownClientApplications": [],
  "logoutUrl": null,
  "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
  "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": true,
```

Not sure what step I'm missing. Thank you!

**Edit**: Right after the token expires, if I run acquireToken(clientID, func), I get "User login is required". However, if I call getCachedUser, I get a user back, after which calling acquireToken returned the timeout error.

Comment: That initial access token you got has a lifetime of 1 hour.  Once it's expired, calling acquireToken will have to go to Azure AD to get a new access token and that's the step it's failing.  It's hard to diagnose the specific issue without more info, can you get a fiddler trace and checkout the error you're getting back from the STS and post back.

Comment: Do you mean the response header from the request URL "https://login.microsoftonline.com/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=...."? If so, I am not getting an error as far as I can see. However, if I give an invalid client ID on acquireToken, then I get the following: "Location:http://<myURL>/#error=invalid_resource...". Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place? I've added a few additional comments to my question above. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed issue by adding call to ADALContext.handleWindowCallback() :)

Comment: @ChristinaK I'm having the same issue. When did you call the handleWindowCallback ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, adal for js will cache the login info into session storage or local storage in browser, depends your configuration in code. You can use chrome's develop tool to have a glance of this table:
[image]

So the `cachaed user` is decoded from `adal.idtoken`. So you can get the cached user. And according the source code of [`acquireToken`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/master/lib/adal.js#L510), it will check whether the login user is exist before renew the access token, which will raise the `User login is required` issue.

To bypass this issue, you can run `getCachedUser()` function before run `acquireToken()` for renewing an access token.

Comment: If I run getCachedUser() before acquireToken(), then I get back a token of null with "Token renewal operation failed due to timeout". Is there a way that I can check if the AAD cookie on the cluster has timed out? I don't think it should after only 1 hour though. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think we can see the such login session or cookie status on AAD IDP server. However, I found a same issue with you on Github, you can try the solution at bottom of https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/391

Comment: If it helps you, you can mark it as the answer, which is benefit for communities who are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and my fix worked. In app.component.ts, add this code to ngOnit().

```
this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
this.adalService.acquireToken(this.adalService.config.loginResource).subscribe(token => {
  this.adalService.userInfo.token = token;
  if (this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated === false) {
    this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated = true;
    this.adalService.userInfo.error = '';
  }
}, error => {
  this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated = false;
  this.adalService.userInfo.error = error;
  this.adalService.login();
});
```

When token expires, app component gets called, and acquire token refreshes the token silently. But the `this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated` is still false leading to redirection or again calling login method. So manually setting it to true fixes the redirection error. `this.adalService.config.loginResource` this is automactically set by adal-angular itself with the resource that we need token for.
Also add  `expireOffsetSeconds: 320`, to adal configuration data settings along with

```
tenant: configData.adalConfig.tenant,
  clientId: configData.adalConfig.clientId,
  redirectUri: window.location.origin,
expireOffsetSeconds: 320
```

expireoffsetseconds invalidates the token based on the time that we specify before its actual expiry.